# Weak cauchy operator sequence over hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Supose that $X$ and $Y$ are two Hilbert spaces and $(T_n)$ a weakly Cauchy sequence. That means for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, $(\langle x, T_ny \rangle )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that exist a linear bounded operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ such that $T_n$ converges weakly to $T$. That means for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ $\langle x, T_ny \rangle \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty } \langle x, Ty \rangle$.

I know if $(T_n)$ is weakly Cauchy sequence then $||T_n||$ is bounded (by Banach-Steinhaus and $||T_n||=\sup_{||x||=||y||=1}|\langle x, T_ny\rangle |$) and $(\langle x, T_ny \rangle )_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} L_{x,y}$ for some $L_{x,y}\in \mathbb{C}$. But I don't know how construct a linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y) $ such that $L_{x,y}=\langle x, Ty \rangle$. How can I construct that if is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riesz representation can do it. Note that
$$
x\mapsto L_{x,y}
$$ defines a bounded linear functional from $X$ into $\mathbb{C}$ for each $y\in Y$ since it holds that
$$
|L_{x,y}|\leq \left(\sup_n \lVert T_n\rVert\right)\lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert\quad\cdots(*).
$$ By Riesz representation theorem, this implies that for each $y\in Y$, there exists unique $\xi_y\in X$ such that
$$
L_{x,y} = \langle x,\xi_y \rangle,
$$ and it holds that
$$
|\xi_y| = \lVert L_{\cdot,y} \rVert\leq \sup_n \lVert T_n\rVert \cdot \lVert y\rVert,
$$ by $(*)$. Finally, note that $y\mapsto \xi_y$ is linear in $y\in Y$. Therefore, by defining a bounded linear operator $T$ as
$$
T : y\in Y\mapsto \xi_y \in X,
$$ we have $L_{x,y} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x,T_ny\rangle = \langle x,Ty\rangle$ and $T$ is a weak limit of $\{T_n\}$.